# Changing a Menu Item Icon during run time

Tags: java, android, icons, android-actionbar

How can I change an Menu Item icon during run time according to an If statement ? This is the code that I have and it results in a crash.

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu Item) {
    if (favorite == true){
        itema = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.action_search);
        itema.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_importants);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the Activity's findViewById, you should have more luck by calling Menu [findItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#findItem%28int%29).

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuItem myMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.myMenuItemId);
    myMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_myAction);
    return true;
}
```